# Tilde delimiters input file, but it has empty values that need to be preserved

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, cmd, split

My problem is can't split the tilde
I/p file:
sample data: only has 5 cols where 2nd col value is blank but delims using tilde operator is showing 2nd field value is 3.

Input file:

```
1~~3~4~5
```

my actual output is

```
field 1: 1
field 2: 3
field 3: 4
field 4: 5
field 5:
```

my expected output should be

```
field 1: 1
field 2: 
field 3: 3
field 4: 4
field 5: 5
```

my expected output should be field 2 output should be blank. Below code demilits comma. I want similar to do for tilde symbol(~)

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%# in (F:\batch\input.txt) do (
pause
    set "LINE=%%#"
    echo Line is:%%#
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    for /F "tokens=1-5 delims=," %%A in (^""!LINE:,="^,"!"^") do (
        endlocal
    echo Field 1: %%~A
    echo Field 2: %%~B
    echo Field 3: %%~C
    echo Field 4: %%~D
    echo Field 5: %%~E
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    endlocal
)
pause
endlocal
```

After reading that post in the comment still I am not able to get the exact output. Can you please advise ?

Comment: Please post genuine representative sample data

Comment: @Magoo Input file is same as i shown in body of the text and also explained. pls check. Thanks for looking.It is just 1~~3 ~4~5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to escape "~" in set/replace command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245802/how-to-escape-in-set-replace-command)

Comment: can you please explain with my input file and code ? I am not getting the exact output.

Comment: Yes.  The For command will treat two consecutive delimiters as one.  I like to use a helper batch file that Dbenham wrote to solve this issue.  http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5702

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q46440111.txt"

FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%A IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%A"
 CALL :replace~ line ":"
 FOR /f "tokens=1-5delims=:" %%a IN ('call echo "%%line%%"' ) DO (
  echo Field 1: %%~a
  echo Field 2: %%~b
  echo Field 3: %%~c
  echo Field 4: %%~d
  echo Field 5: %%~e
 )
)


GOTO :EOF

:replace~
CALL SET "$=%%%1%%"
SET "%1="
:replace~l
IF NOT DEFINED $ GOTO :EOF 
IF "%$:~0,1%"=="~" (CALL SET "%1=%%%1%%%2") ELSE (CALL SET "%1=%%%1%%%$:~0,1%")
SET "$=%$:~1%"
GOTO replace~l
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q46440111.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Since you appear to want to operate with `delayedexpansion` disabled, I've not invoked it.

The line read from the file is assigned to `line` and this variable is processed by the routine `replace~` to mechanically replace each `~` with the second argument supplied to the routine.

The result is then parsed by the second `for` and the individual elements reported.

Comment: Thanks a lot Magoo.. It worked perfectly. The only thing is it is taking 20 seconds to process 5 records. I have to process 1 million records. Is there anyway to reduce the execution time?

Comment: Batch is notoriously slow and was never designed to tackle a problem of such dimension. I would use 3rd-party utilities like `sed` or `(g)awk` or write a program in a high-level language.

Comment: If i have the input file like this 1~2~test) ~4 ~5 it got exited due to close paranthesis. Any idea?

Comment: There are many symbols that have special meaning for `cmd`, but no universal method to smoothly process all of them. This is why I requested a representative data sample. Each "poison" character has its own work-around method, and using workarounds will add significantly to the processing time - which you've already said is excessive. Batch is not a suitable language for general string-processing and I believe you should investigate `sed` or `(g)awk` to perform your task.